# Creating higher order functions using Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I have recently been teaching myself Haskell, and one of my exercises was to implement a function that takes two arguments: a list and a single value. The function would check if the value is in the list twice or more. I cannot use the function element or member.

I tried removing the values that are not equal to the value. Then checking for the size of the new list if its more than 1 then it outputs `True` if not it outputs `False`. I having problem trying to use a function inside a function.

```
remove2 val [] = []
remove2 val (x:xs) = if ( not (x == val))
                         then remove2 val xs 
                         else x:remove2 val xs

isMemberTwice :: (Eq val) => val -> [val] -> Bool 
isMemberTwice val [] = False
isMemberTwice val (x:xs) 
     | ( >= (length (remove2 val [val])) 2) = True
         | otherwise = a `isMemberTwice’` xs
```

Comment: How is this related to higher order functions?

Comment: @DanielJour i'm really not sure but aren't curried functions a high order function? Isn't calling a function inside another a high order function.

Comment: @LuisFernandoPineda: no and no: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A higher order function is a function that takes another function as argument or returns another function.

Your problem at hand is easily solvable using a short [recursive function:](http://ideone.com/rhtYza)

```
memtwice :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
memtwice value list = scan value list False
 where scan _ [] _ = False
       scan v (x:xs) True =
         if v == x then True
          else scan v xs True
       scan v (x:xs) False =
         scan v xs (v == x)
```

The `scan` is a function that carries state information (whether there has already been found one instance) as additional parameter.

One could rewrite this using higher order functions such as `fold` though I'm not sure how one could implement the short circuit behaviour (stopping as soon as two instances have been found) then.

Comment: I took the liberty of continuing from your last note below.

Answer (score 1):

Every function on a list can be written in this form:

```
f     [] = ...   -- also called the "base case"
f (a:as) = ...   -- also called the recursive case
```

Let's apply this idea to writing a function which determine the number 3 appears in a list at least once:

```
hasA3 :: [Int] -> Bool
hasA3  []     = ...
hasA3  (a:as) = ...
```

Clearly `hasA3 [] = False`. I'll leave you to figure out how to write the recursive case. Hint: the function might have to check if a == 3.

Now let's write a function which determines if a list contains two or more threes. Again we start with the two cases:

```
hasTwo3s :: [Int] -> Bool
hasTwo3s []     = ...
hasTwo3s (a:as) = ...
```

Again, the base case is easy. Hints for the recursive case: you might have to check if a == 3 and then you might want to use the `hasA3` function.

Answer (score 1):

I will add to [Daniel Jour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384233/3234959) starting from its final note:

> One could rewrite this using higher order functions such as `fold`
>   though I'm not sure how one could implement the short circuit
>   behaviour (stopping as soon as two instances have been found) then.

Let's transform the original code:

```
memtwice value list = scan value list False
 where scan _ [] _ = False
       scan v (x:xs) True =
         if v == x then True
          else scan v xs True
       scan v (x:xs) False =
         scan v xs (v == x)
```

Moving to boolean operators we get:

```
memtwice value list = scan value list False
 where scan _ [] _ = False
       scan v (x:xs) True  = v == x || scan v xs True
       scan v (x:xs) False = scan v xs (v == x)
```

Now, the parameter `v` is always `value`, so let's remove the parameter.

```
memtwice value list = scan list False
 where scan [] _ = False
       scan (x:xs) True  = value == x || scan xs True
       scan (x:xs) False = scan xs (value == x)
```

Introducing an explicit lambda for the last argument (not really needed, but helps readability):

```
memtwice value list = scan list False
 where scan [] = (\_ -> False)
       scan (x:xs) = \found -> if found 
                                 then value == x || scan xs True
                                 else scan xs (value == x)
```

We now see that the last recursion pattern is a `foldr`: indeed we have a base-case definition for `scan []`, and the recursive case `scan (x:xs)` is defined only in terms of `scan xs`.

```
memtwice value list = foldr go (\_ -> False) list False
 where go x next = \found -> if found 
                                 then value == x || next True
                                 else next (value == x)
```

Note that `foldr` seems to be called with *four* parameters. This is because `go x next` produces a function, hence `foldr go (\_ -> False) list` does as well. We can now revert the explicit lambda.

```
memtwice value list = foldr go (\_ -> False) list False
 where go x next True  = value == x || next True
       go x next False = next (value == x)
```

Finally, note that since `||` has short-circuiting behaviour, we did achieve an equivalent `foldr` to the original code.

Comment: Awesome :) I didn't think about short circuiting behavior of `||` when I first approached a `fold` based solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way really:

```
isMemberTwice needle haystack = n >= 2
  where n = length $ filter (== needle) haystack
```

However, the downside with this approach is that, if you pass it a really long list, it'll evaluate the entire list, which is unnecessary: you only need to see if there are *at least* 2 occurrences of `needle`.

So a better solution is to avoid using `length` on the filtered list and instead just use pattern match: if it matches `(_:_:_)`, there must be at least 2 occurrences:

```
isMemberTwice needle haystack = case occurrences of (_:_:_) -> True
                                                    _       -> False
  where occurrences = filter (== needle) haystack
```

Comment: This is clever :) Maybe you should add that the later code relies on lazy evaluation to achieve its short circuiting behavior.